# 401.2 status code custom page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, custom-errors

ASP.NET Custom Error page not working for the **401.2 status code**.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="401.htm">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="401.htm"></error>
</customErrors>
```

There is not any problem for the other status codes. How can I handle this status code?

Comment: And that's your only `customErrors` element in your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Add subStatusCode="2" to the error config.

Comment: subStatusCode is not allowed in web.config file.

Comment: I will use ASP.NET web site, .NET Framework 3.5. SubStatusCode is not allowed.